# Multi thread PHP

Tags: php, laravel, multithreading

I have a problem with multi-thread in PHP, I want when call function FunctionAync, after it returned, it still processes function Process (currently, it only returns after finishing process function Process), what should i do?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Helper;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Spatie\Async\Pool;

class AsyncTask

{
    function functionAsync(Request $request){
        $pool = Pool::create();
        $pool->add(function () use ($request){

        $this->Process($request);

        })->then(function ($output) {
            return;
        })->catch(function (Throwable $exception) {
            return;
        });
        await($pool);
        return;
    }
    function Process($request){
        sleep(1000);
    }
}
```